# Search in specific content type

Tags: 6, search

I want to make a custom search box but I only want to allow users to search in a specific content type. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These modules may help: [Custom Search](http://drupal.org/project/custom_search), [Search Configuration](http://drupal.org/project/search_config)

Answer (score 0):

If you use D7 check search configuration page.

Comment: I use drupal version 6